# Generics in Kotlin with extends

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, mvp, extends

I trying to porting java project to kotlin and have some problems with it. I have some MVP structure in java using generics

```
interface View<P extends Presenter> {}
interface Presenter<V extends View> {}
interface BaseView<P extends Presenter> extends View<P> {}

class BaseActivity<P extends Presenter> extends AppCompatActivity implements BaseView<P> {}
```

At first two classes I have error from IDE

```
interface Presenter<V : View<*>> {}
interface View<P : Presenter<*>> {}
```

my error is

```
*this type parameter violates the finite bound restriction*
```

No any problem with Java code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose this is not allowed in Kotlin.

From the [Kotlin spec](https://jetbrains.github.io/kotlin-spec/#_finite_bound_restriction):

> The following pair of declarations is invalid, because there are edges
> T → S and S → T, forming a cycle:
>
> `interface B<T : C<*>>`
>
> `interface C<S : B<*>>`

The reason stated as:

> In its fully expanded form this bound would be infinite. The purpose
> of this rule is to avoid such infinite types, and type checking
> difficulties associated with them.

In your case, it is V -> P and P -> V forms a cycle.